# How can I make the empty value stay inside the input after changing the input type to hidden and to text again?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

I have html input and a button in a template:

```
  <button (click)="toggleHidden()">Toggle hidden.</button>

  <input [type]="hidden ? 'hidden' : 'text'" value="text"/>
```

And variable and a method in a component:

```
  public hidden = false;

  public toggleHidden() {
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
  }
```

Now, when I modify the text in the input, and press the button twice, the text stays modified.
However, when I completely remove the text from the input, and press the button twice, the most recent nonempty value of the input gets restored.

Is it a bug in angular/html, or is it proper behavior and I am doing something wrong?

Here is the example of this behavior:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q6qwcf?file=src%2Fmain.ts

I am hiding the input so I can still submit its value, and when I bind it to a variable, then whatever I enter stays on the variable (including empty value) and is properly submitted, but this ghost value in the input is bugging me - the input is showing what WAS on the variable before I cleared it, not what is there ACTUALLY (the empty value).

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: seems odd to change the type. Why not just show and hide the element.